# Using new columns in the "where" clause

Tags: sql, hive

`hive` rejects this code:

```
select a, b, a+b as c
from t
where c > 0
```

saying `Invalid table alias or column reference 'c'`.

do I really need to write something like

```
select * from 
(select a, b, a+b as c
 from t)
where c > 0
```

EDIT:

1. the computation of `c` it complex enough for me not to want to repeat it in `where a + b > 0`
2. I need a solution which would work in `hive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expression if you want to use derived columns.

```
with x as
(
select a, b, a+b as c
from t
)
select * from x where c >0
```

Comment: this calls `select` twice - how is this different from my own solution?

Comment: it's a CTE, not a derived table. but the short answer to your question is that you cannot reference a derived column in the WHERE clause - this is just a little more readable than a derived table.

Answer (score 3):

You can run this query like this or with a Common Table Expression

```
select a, b, a+b as c
from t
where a+b > 0
```

Reference the below order of operations for logical query processing to know if you can use derived columns in another clause.

Keyed-In Order

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. WHERE
4. GROUP BY
5. HAVING
6. ORDER BY

Logical Querying Processing Phases

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you can do this

```
select a, b, a+b as c
from t
where a+b > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It would have to look like this:

```
select a, b, a+b as c
from t
where a+b > 0
```

An easy way to explain/remember this is this:  SQL cannot reference aliases assigned within its own instance.  It would, however, work if you did this:

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM(
select a, b, a+b as c
from t) as [calc]
WHERE c > 0
```

This syntax would work because the alias is assigned in a subquery.

Comment: what is `[calc]`? how is this different from my solution?

Comment: [calc] is just an alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

no

just:

select a, b, a+b as c
from t
where a+b > 0

note: for mysql at least: order by and group by you can use column (or expression) positions

e.g. group by 2, order by 1 would get you one row per column 2 (whether a field name or an expression) and order it by column 1 (field or expression)

also: some RDBMS's do let you refer to the column alias as you first attempted